# Downsampling point clouds to specific number of points while retaining shape

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, downsampling

Environment: Python-PCL, WIndows 10, Python 3.6

I need to downsample point clouds to a specific number of points. These point clouds vary in size and hence I am stuck. From going through documentation, I understand there are only 
`VoxelGrid`, `ConditionalOutlierRemoval` ,`StatisticalOutlierRemoval` and `RadiusOutlierRemoval`   are the options available.

In VoxelGrid, the leaf size doesnt guarantee the number of points, Radius removal doesnt help in retaining the shape, and statistical outlier mostly helps in removing noise.

Is there any solution to this? It is possible to use `numpy.random.choice()`and hoping for a miracle?

EDIT: `numpy.random.choice` works but only if you don't care about the geometric shape of your point cloud, which I do. Anyway to use VoxelGrid dynamically?

Comment: If you use `numpy.random.choice` are the results suitable for your purposes?  That seems like the easiest choice.

Comment: The results are a complete hit and miss. Sometimes it does preserve the geometric shape and sometimes it doesn't. I want to try VoxelGrid but since I have pointclouds from 500 points to 7000 points in shape, I am looking for a way to make the leaf size dynamic in accordance with the density of the point cloud.

Comment: @kav I'm facing the same issue. Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. The number of output points using PCL's VoxelGrid is always going to be a function of the number of occupied voxels. The only way to control the number of occupied voxels is by altering the leaf size, and there is no dynamic way of doing this.

Alternately, you may have luck using Farthest Point Sampling, as it would allow you to select N points and has nice blue noise properties, but to the best of my knowledge this is not available in PCL.

Comment: I realised this too later. Leaf Size and the output cloud are not linearly related. I tried the numpy method which is very hit and miss, but is there any alternate libary in python I can use to work with point clouds? So dar I only know python-pcl. Even though they mention in the documentation that point clouds can be treated as numpy arrays, I am not entirely sure about that since the geometrtic shape will be severely compromised.